# How to find all n-digit numbers with a given digitsum?

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I am looking for an algorithm, that is able to find all numbers, that are `n` digits long and have the sum of their digits equal to `x`. As the code is part of a large program, a low time complexity is desired.

Examples:

```
findNumbers(2,5)
```

> [14, 23, 32, 41, 50]

```
findNumbers(10,90)
```

> [9999999999]

The code below seems to find the desired numbers, but is a bit inefficient. For example `findNumbers(5, 5)` needs to check 10000 numbers while only 70 are accepted. With higher `n` this mismatch makes it very slow.

What would be a faster approach?

```py
def firstNumber(n, x):
    # find the first number of n digits with x as sum of digits
    num9 = (x-1) // 9 # number of nines needed at the end of said first number
    f = 10**(n-1) # the first digit should be a 1 (or higher, if there are already n-1 nines)
    f += 10**num9 - 1 # num9 nines
    f += 10**num9 * (x - 1 - 9*num9) # add the rest just before the 9s
    return f

def sumOfDigits(x):
    s = 0
    while x > 0:
        s += x % 10
        x //= 10
    return s

def findNumbers(n, x, allow_all=False):
    f = firstNumber(n, x)
    nums = []
    while f < 10**n:
        if allow_all or sumOfDigits(f) == x:
            nums.append(f)
        f += 9 # if the sum of digits is x, all numbers must be equal modulo 9
    return nums

findNumbers(3, 5) # [104, 113, 122, 131, 140, 203, 212, 221, 230, 302, 311, 320, 401, 410, 500]
```

Comment: Where's your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What I have is so messy, that I decided not to put it in here. It returns weird results and does not come close to doing its job.

Comment: Do you care about time complexity?

Comment: Yes, I do, as it will be part of a bigger algorithm, that I need to go fast.

Comment: @Mesalcode That sound like you're trying to get solution for your assignment. Stackoverflow isn't right place for that. If you have concrete question, you should provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What about `41`, `14`?

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin No, i am not looking for a solution for a assignment. I am building a python script for myself and this is a step I need for a bigger process. How can I improve my examples? They show how I imagine calling the function and what it should return.

Comment: @DaniMesejo oh you're right. I will add this to the example.

Comment: Hint: what happens if you add `9` to a number? Or `99` or ...?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I don't quite get what you are hinting. Could you help me a little with what you are trying to get me to understand?

Comment: So, by _n long_ you mean _n_ decimal digits ?  And by _checksum_ you mean the sum of those decimal digits ?  Are leading zeros allowed in the _n_ digit values ?  This looks as though the number of numbers will explode as _n_ gets bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code finds all the desired numbers. There is a parameter `max_in_group` in you want to run with other bases than base 10.

The code first creates a list `a` of `num_digits` values. Each entry in the list represents one digit. To make the code more general, a maximum digit can be set. It would be `9` for decimal, or `7` for octagonal. Or even `999` if 3 decimals digits are taken together. (The printing now prints everything decimal, but could be easily adapted for bases larger than 10.)

This array `a` doesn't necessarily need to always have all digits lower than 10. The first step redistributes the overflow of the last digit to the earlier ones. The code now stops when the overflow would need an extra digit.

In step 2 the successor is sought. If there wouldn't be overflows, just 1 needs to be added to the penultimate digit. This creates a surplus (for the digitsum) that should be subtracted again from the last digit. When the penultimate digit grows too large (it already is 9), it needs to be set to 0 and the earlier number should be incremented, etc..

In the third step, the last digit needs to be adjusted with the surplus. This could result in an overflow, which is handled in step 1.

To obtain numbers starting with zero, `a` can be initialized with `[0, ..., 0, desired_sum]`. To only obtain the numbers starting with `1` or higher, `a` should be initialized with `[1, 0, ..., 0, desired_sum-1]`.

Note that as Python doesn't have a `do ... while` or `repeat ... until` construction such as in C-like languages, these loops need to be written with `while True` and `break`.

```py
def find_nunbers(num_digits, desired_sum, max_iterations=100, max_in_digit=9):
    a = [0 for i in range(num_digits)]
    a[0] = desired_sum - 1
    a[num_digits - 1] = 1
    all_numbers_found = False
    while not all_numbers_found and max_iterations > 0:
        # step 1: while a[0] is too large: redistribute to the left
        i = 0
        while a[i] > max_in_digit:
            if i == num_digits - 1:
                all_numbers_found = True
                break
            a[i + 1] += a[i] - max_in_digit
            a[i] = max_in_digit
            i += 1
        if all_numbers_found:
            break

        num = sum(10 ** i * a[i] for i, n in enumerate(a))
        print(f"{num:}")  # print(a[::-1])

        # step 2:  add one to the penultimate group, while group already full: set to 0 and increment the
        #   group left of it;
        #   while the surplus is too large (because a[0] is too small) repeat the incrementing
        i0 = 1
        surplus = 0
        while True:  # needs to be executed at least once, and repeated if the surplus became too large
            i = i0
            while True:  # increment a[i] by 1, which can carry to the left
                if i == len(a):
                    all_numbers_found = True
                    break
                else:
                    if a[i] == max_in_digit:
                        a[i] = 0
                        surplus -= max_in_digit
                        i += 1
                    else:
                        a[i] += 1
                        surplus += 1
                        break
            if all_numbers_found:
                break
            if a[0] >= surplus:
                break
            else:
                surplus -= a[i0]
                a[i0] = 0
                i0 += 1

        # step 3: a[0] should absorb the surplus created in step 1, although a[0] can get out of bounds
        a[0] -= surplus
        surplus = 0
        max_iterations -= 1

find_nunbers(2, 5)
find_nunbers(10, 90)
find_nunbers(20, 90)
```

Note that there are `2785022004925340460` 20-digit numbers with 90 as digitsum, so outputting them all won't be possible.

Comment: I know im not supposed to thank in a comment, but this solution is simply great. Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you explain in words what your code is doing?